# Sort digits of a given integer, without '0'

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort the digits of a given integer by turning the integer to a String and creating an array by the size of that String length.
I'm using the modulu option to separate the digits and in the end I'm reversing it by multiplying by 10.
The problem that it's going out of bound each time and I don't know how to make the size of the array to work good for me.
Here are the code :

```
String s = String.valueOf(num);
        int[] arr = new int[s.length()+1];    
        while(num != 0) {
            arr[(int) num % 10]++;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        long result = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length - 1 ; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr[i] ; j++) {
                result = result * 10;
                result = result + i;
            }
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: What exactly is `arr[(int) num % 10]++;` meant to do? This would basically extract the last digit of `num` and count it. If you want to do that your array needs to be able to hold 10 digits so its length should be 10. However, this would just count the frequency of each digit in the number not the digits themselves, i.e. `1211` would not result in the array `[1,2,1,1]` but int the array `[0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: If you want to collect the digits just use an index into the array that you're incrementing or decrementing in each iteration, e.g. `int i = 0; while(...) { arr[i] = num % 10; i++ }` (this would reverse the digits but if you want to sort them anyway order wouldn't matter here).

Comment: Please step through your code with a debugger. You'll soon see that you haven't thought out the length of `arr` correctly.

Comment: @Thomas how should I know how much digits should I make room for?

Comment: @tgdavies This was my main problem, I did not understand how to make the length correctly. But thank's for the help, I'm sorry for the noob question.

Comment: "how should I know how much digits should I make room for?" - that depends: Do you want to collect individual digits in a number? Then use the length of the string but a different index and method when setting the values. Do you want to count how often a digit appears? In that case the digits themselves would probably be the indices into an array of lenth 10 and your method of incrementing the array elements is correct.

Comment: @Thomas you helped a lot, I've made the size as much as there are numbers (0-9) and it work's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a lot of overkill solving this, as in a lot of code, so here is my take on it.

```java
static int sortDigits(int num) {
    char[] arr = Integer.toString(num).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(arr));
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(sortDigits(4201514)); // 112445
```

You can of course do the same for the `long` and `BigInteger` versions:

```java
static long sortDigits(long num) {
    char[] arr = Long.toString(num).toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return Long.parseLong(new String(arr));
}
```

```java
static BigInteger sortDigits(BigInteger num) {
    char[] arr = num.toString().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return new BigInteger(new String(arr));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what the OP is trying to do (since I kept 0's in the same place and sorted the rest of the numbers). Your solution looks very simple though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, when given an integer, you want to "sort" each digit, ignoring 0's.

To do so, so you can first convert it to a string:

```
String value = String.valueOf(num);
```

Since you have a string, you can use the `split()` function to split each 'number' like so:

```
String[] numbers = value.split("");
```

Then, you can find the indexes of 0's (and store it somewhere).

```
ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i].equals("0")) {
        indexes.add(i);
    }
}
```

Then, you can sort the array of strings (`numbers`) using the `sort()` function:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

Then, you can remove the 0's like this (by creating a new `ArrayList`):

```
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : numbers) {
    if (!s.equals("0")) {
        copy.add(s);
    }
}
```

(Here, you may use `ArrayUtils` if you already imported the library.)

Then, concatenate each element to make one entire string with `join()`:

```
String result = String.join("", copy);
```

Finally, using the `indexes`, insert 0's to where they were located at initially:

```
for (int i : indexes) {
    result = result.substring(0, i) + "0" + result.substring(i);
}
```

`result` would be what you want.

Note: This might not be the most sufficient way to do it, so you can modify it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I made a few modification

1. size of array should be 10 since in a number only 0 to 9 digits are possible
2. use this array to make a frequency array of occurrence of each digit
3. iterate over the array from 1 to 9 and make a sorted number

```java
public static long sortInt(long num) {
    
    int[] arr = new int[10];

    while(num != 0) {
        arr[(int) num % 10] ++;
        num /= 10;
    }

    long result = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
        while(arr[i]-- != 0)
            result = result * 10 + i;
    
    return result;
}
```